# How come when I 'Browse Network' in Nautilus it says Windows Network?

Tags: networking, samba

This is a Samba thing, yes?

What file can I edit to change that name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is normal. I am not sure you can edit this.
As it is supposed to act as a Windows File/Print Server or Client.